# Loss of precision and accuracy, issues with saving dataframes as csv files

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

Loss of precision and accuracy, issues with saving dataframes as csv files

I have an issue with saving my pandas dataframes as CSV files where the data being changed loses their actual exponents and is converted into a completely different version.  When I print the numbers being saved on my terminal, they occur as:

```
5.991147508039374e-14
0.00010245463935037415
0.12370028677066161
3.441345557219637e-10
1.0513129941379549e-11
0.00012962879921246142
0.0012641841232159863
5.5991400151355556e-11
1.607061744727683e-20
0.6436355784804926
```

But when I open the corresponding excel file: the corresponding rows have the following numbers:

```
5.99E+01
0.000102
0.1237
3.44E+05
1.05E+05
0.00013
0.001264
5.60E+05
1.61E-05
0.643636
```

Clearly, these numbers are completely different from the actual data being saved. This is catastrophic for my data analysis because the original data corresponds to p values. Data whose values were significant is saved as not significant affecting the interpretation of my results.

I tried the regular `pd.to_csv(df_data)` format to save such data, I also tried specifying the float format and delimiter as follows:

```
pd.to_csv(df_data, float_format='%.15f',sep= ",")
```

I encountered this issue too when I copied a number let's say, `5.991147508039374e-14` into an Excel cell and it got converted to
`5.99E+01`.

I have checked the previous query (below) on issues involving CSV and tried recommended solutions to no avail.
[pandas to_csv: suppress scientific notation in csv file when writing pandas to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22995762/pandas-to-csv-suppress-scientific-notation-in-csv-file-when-writing-pandas-to-c) and
[Prevent trailing zero with pandas "to_csv"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56345170/prevent-trailing-zero-with-pandas-to-csv)

Comment: Hard to answer without any reproducible example. But are you sure that this is not an Excel problem? How your CSV looks like? Are the number truncated in CSV too?

Comment: If you open the csv file in a text editor *without having previously opened and saved it in Excel* are the values there as expected? Maybe have a look at how Excel works with floats: [Microsoft Learn | Floating-point arithmetic may give inaccurate results in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result)